# надо в Odoo 11 открыть офисный документ(.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx) в новом окне, а не загружать его?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

надо в Odoo 11 открыть офисный документ(.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx) в новом окне браузера, а не загружать его? Кто может помочь? помогите

Comment: `doc`, `xls` - бинарные данные, а вот `docx`, `xlsx` - зазипованный `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

можно посмотреть как это реализовано в [этом](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/muk_web_preview_msoffice/) модуле предосмотра офисных документов и реализовать на его основе.
Там используется библиотека pdfconv. Офисные документы конвертируются в ПДФ и показываются в браузере.

Comment: MuK Preview MS Office не работает, пробовал

Comment: Я не предлагал вам пользоваться этим модулем. Я предложил вам вариант решения вашей задачи, основываясь на реализации в этом модуле.
Но судя по постановке вопроса и ответам, вы не разработчик, а просто ищете горовое решение. Такое наврядли существует.